# permission denied in running script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am running a script but there is an unusual warning:
This is what happened in my console

```
#whoami
root
#ls -l test.sh
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1894 Feb  2 01:58 test.sh
#./test.sh
-bash: ./test.sh: Permission denied
```

Edit:
my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read pass port user ip file; do
  echo "startt------------------------------------" $ip
  ping $ip -c 4
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo $ip ok...
  else
    echo $ip failed...
  fi
  echo "finish------------------------------------" $ip
done <<____HERE
pass  22  root  1.1.1.1  test.txt
____HERE
```

any idea?
thank you

Comment: no guy..I tested it

Comment: I notice that there's a `.` after the permissions, which indicates that an SELinux security context applies to that file. That's probably what's preventing you from running the script. Are you in a directory where it might be a bad idea for executables to reside?

Comment: don't put your comment as answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that there's a `.` after the permissions, which indicates that an SELinux security context applies to that file. That's probably what's preventing you from running the script. Are you in a directory where it might be a bad idea for executables to reside?